# Unexpected token { when importing a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

Here's a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bhaskara-knfjt?file=/pages/index.vue)

with this import I get the error(10 line index.vue):

```
import { EffectComposer } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js";
```

so what's going on here? The other ES6 imports are fine.

Comment: I'm not an expert but other imports doesn't have the curly brackets... maybe you could remove them to see if it fix your problem.

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf still the same

Comment: Can you show what/how `EffectComposer` is exporting? For example is it doing `export ...` or `export default ...` it could make a difference when you are importing.

Comment: @TomO. `export { EffectComposer, Pass };`, [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js#L311)

Comment: @s0up did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem, which makes Threejs in Nuxt pretty much unusable: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460871/importing-with-curly-braces-inside-a-nuxt-component)

Comment: @dan No, I've asked about this problem like in 4 different places and no one helped. The only way I know to make these jsm/examples modules work is to copy them into your project and change the imports inside them. As for Orbit Controls in your question, you can use this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/orbit-controls-es6, it should work

Answer (score 1):

I commented above about having the same problem. Meanwhile I came across this [project](https://github.com/osorina/3d-headphones) and wondered why it works. **Long story short, it's configured as a SPA. I tried the same with my project and it works.**

So in *nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
  mode: "spa",
  ..
```

So I guess the problem has to do with server-side rendering.

------ Some notes on Universal Mode ------

Since I wanted to use my app in universal mode I also tried to do conditional import of plugins.
**Note that the approach below doesn't work.** I do include it though, SPA might not be an option and it could point you in the right direction.

Move

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
Vue.use(OrbitControls)
```

into a *threeimports.js* file in the plugins folder and add

```
  plugins: [
   { src :"~/plugins/threeimports.js", ssr: false},
  ..
```

to the *nuxt.config.js*

I thought OrbitControls should be available from anywhere in the project, but it's not. It has to do with the curly bracket syntax, since the same mechanism works well with other modules that don't use the bracket syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of the file where you want to import from, but are you trying to import a default or just a module?

Because the default syntax does not have `{}`. Much like your first import. If what you're trying to import is set as a default export, you need to remove those brackets.

Read about [import in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: I'm trying to import a module from [this file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js)