# Importing with curly braces inside a Nuxt component

Tags: javascript, three.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to import Three.js in a Nuxt component.

```
<script>
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
..
```

While the first line works, the second one gives me an *"Unexpected token {" - syntax error*, so does

```
const { OrbitControls } = require('three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls')
```

The syntax of the import (the first version) is per Three.js documentation.

Comment: You should only perform ES6 imports in script tags that look like so: `<script type="module">`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Mugen87 I'm not the only one with this problem and it only happens with Three.js modules: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63850866/unexpected-token-when-importing-a-module)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question by copying an answer I gave in another thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63850866/unexpected-token-when-importing-a-module/64602826#64602826)

Meanwhile I came across this [project](https://github.com/osorina/3d-headphones) and wondered why it works. **Long story short, it's configured as a SPA. I tried the same with my project and it works.**

So in *nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
  mode: "spa",
  ..
```

So I guess the problem has to do with server-side rendering.

------ Some notes on Universal Mode ------

Since I wanted to use my app in universal mode I also tried to do conditional import of plugins.
**Note that the approach below doesn't work.** I do include it though, SPA might not be an option and it could point you in the right direction.

Move

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
Vue.use(OrbitControls)
```

into a *threeimports.js* file in the plugins folder and add

```
  plugins: [
   { src :"~/plugins/threeimports.js", ssr: false},
  ..
```

to the *nuxt.config.js*

I thought OrbitControls should be available from anywhere in the project, but it's not. It has to do with the curly bracket syntax, since the same mechanism works well with other modules that don't use the bracket syntax.