# Use dynamic routes in Nuxt SPA after generating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use dynamic routes in a Nuxt SPA. I know how to use dynamic routes in Universal Mode and I know how to generate them during build time using functions but I'm looking for something where I don't need to re-build with every new entry in a database for instance.

My web-app allows users to create content (via Strapi backend) that should be immediately accessible in a form like *[www.domain.com/content/uniqe_id](http://www.domain.com/content/uniqe_id)* (without rebuilding the project)
Is this possible? Can I create something like the */content/index.vue* that has access to the parameters and fetch the right content?

On a side-note: I would prefer to use Universal Mode for several reasons, but I'm using Three.js in my project and the only way to get it to work is to use SPA. I've posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460871/importing-with-curly-braces-inside-a-nuxt-component)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SPA mode, you don't really need to worry about dynamic routes, as everything is rendered on the client. The only thing you would need to take care of, is setting up your production server to always redirect to your `index.html`, so you don't get a 404 when accessing other pages.

---

If you are using Universal you could still generate a SPA fallback for handling your dynamic routes on the client side, by adding this to your `nuxt.config.js`:

[Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#fallback)

```json
generate: {
  fallback: true,
  // ...
},
```

Using this, Nuxt generates a 404.html which will render the page in SPA mode, instead of showing a 404, while the other routes are generated like normal.

If you want to properly generate all routes and have instant access, you could use this technique to show users a temporary SPA version of your page, until the page is rebuilt.